Matrix form PCA
Background
Given

Data points matrix $X$ is given.

We look for $W$, an orthonormal column matrix
$$
W = \begin{bmatrix}
| & | & & | \\
w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_k \\
| & | & & |
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times l} \mid w_i^\top w_j=\delta_{i,j}
$$
such that the approximation of $X$ is $WW^\top X$.

$W$ should minimize the mean-square error
$$MSE(W)=\sum_{j=1}^n\|x_j-WW^\top x_j\|^2$$

Let $G=X^\top X$.

It is known that the function
$$K(W)=\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^\top Gw_i=\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^\top X^\top Xw_i$$
Is maximized by the eigenvectors of $G$.


Requirement
Show that the eigenvectors of $G=X^\top X$ minimizes $MSE(W)$.
Attempt
Expanding (3)
$$MSE(W)=...=\sum_{j=1}^n
\left[x_j^\top x_j - x_j^\top WW^\top x_j\right]
$$
The first summation term is given, so we look to maximize the term
$$\sum_{j=1}^n
x_j^\top WW^\top x_j
$$
However, I'm unable to translate it into term (5)
$$\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^\top X^\top Xw_i$$
Question

Is the following true
$$\sum_{j=1}^n
x_j^\top WW^\top x_j=\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^\top X^\top Xw_i \;?$$

If it is, then why?

If it is not true, then are there any missing requirements for it to be true?

Is there another way to prove the requirement?



What does $(W^\top x_j)^2$ mean?  There is no general defined operation called "squaring" a vector.  Also why do you block $W$ as having columns $\mathbf w_j$ in bold then immediately refer to them as $w_j$ (which seems more like scalars)?

@user8675309 thank you for your comments. I've edited accordingly: replaced the bold w with a regular w and replaced the undefined vector square with a well-defined term.
